# Stripchart in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Any idea how to draw stripchart in ggplot2? The example in base R is pasted below.

```
stripchart(iris$Sepal.Length, col = "red", method="stack")
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `geom_dotplot`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_dotplot()
```

[image]

Comment: What is the meaning of the numbers on the vertical axis?

Comment: @JanHlavacekn From the help package of `?geom_dotplot`: `When binning along the x axis and stacking along the y axis, the numbers on y axis are not meaningful, due to technical limitations of ggplot2.`